# An exception apears while deploying KIE Execution Server

Tags: optaplanner, kie-workbench, kie-server

I want to delpoy the Execution Server in follwing environment:

Wildfly17.0.0.Final
JVM memory, min:64m, max:1024m
Execution Server WAR package: kie-server-7.22.0.Final-ee7.war

A message shows in deployment page of Wildfly's HAL Management Console:

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"kie-server-7.22.0.Final-ee7.war\".PARSE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"kie-server-7.22.0.Final-ee7.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found"}}
```

can someone help? thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the full error message in the log?

Comment: I changed the configuration to standalone-full.xml, it's could be deploy successfully. Thanks, Geoffrey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you started WildFly with default standalone profile. However Kie server requires standalone-full profile as it uses JMS queues.

Please try to start WildFly with standalone-full profile. For linux based system you can achieve that using command:

```
./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml
```

Comment: Yes, I changed the configuration to standalone-full.xml, it works. Thank you, Karel.